# continue typing below a table

Tags: formatting

I have constructed a table in latex. I have left a space below (end table) and started typing but the text is still appearing above my table. How can I resolve this

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please try to provide a minimal but working example. Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8625/237192 help?

Comment: Problably the table is searching the bottom of the page because in the middle of text is not very elegant. See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)